# Flask app return string doesn't display <abc>

Tags: html, flask, tags

I tried to display a string on a webpage with this Flask code:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Variable can be of different types: string and <int>'
```

and got

```
Variable can be of different types: string and
```

without "<>".
A way to fix it is to add a space between "<" and "int" like:

```
Variable can be of different types: string and < int >.
```

Also I noticed that the space for the closing > as in "< int>" doesn't matter.

Other characters such as [int] and {int} have no such a problem. Why? tag related?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is tags related, it gonna be shows up like this

[image]

If you use the less than (<) or greater than (>) signs in your text, the browser might mix them with tags.

However, if you want to still display that, you can just do this
[image]

For more reference, [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp)

Comment: But there is no such an [HTML tag](https://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/default.asp) as <int> and yet it didn't flag an error?

Comment: edited my answer, sorry for not being clear. @LeonChang

Comment: Now I understand that HTML is parsed and rendered by browser or fixed [permissively](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/Debugging_HTML). There are no syntax errors to flag. Browsers have built-in rules to state how to interpret incorrectly written markup, However, we can debug with the help of [DOM inspector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) or [Markup Validation Service](https://validator.w3.org/).